# calculate between 2 row 2 column and different userID - SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a pretty long list (10000+ records) where I need to calculate the time between end and start off the related UserID.

So - I have an UserID, StartDate (datetime) and EndDate (datetime).

I tried to get along with this code - but I do not get what I need - the time between Start and End of each individual User. How can I add the "UserID" part - to get the difference between end and start of next row of a UserID?

```
declare @MyTable table
(UserID int, StartDate datetime, FinishDate datetime);

insert into @MyTable values
('1', '2013-11-25 14:25', '2013-11-25 16:35'),
('2', '2013-12-01 10:20', '2013-12-02 12:20'),
('2', '2013-12-06 09:15', '2013-12-06 16:15'),
('1', '2013-12-08 08:00', '2013-12-08 16:30'),
('1', '2013-12-09 07:45', '2013-12-15 09:45');


with CTE_RN as
(
    select
        StartDate,
        FinishDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartDate) as RN
    from @MyTable
)

select
    f.FinishDate,
    s.StartDate,
    DATEDIFF(minute, f.FinishDate, s.StartDate) as DifHours
from CTE_RN as f
inner join CTE_RN as s
    on s.RN = f.RN + 1
```

I edit this - as there was some confusion in my first description.

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific database you're using, you'll get better answers that way.

Comment: Thanks for the input... MS SQL 2012

Comment: You need to put it in the tags, not a comment. I've done it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `LEAD()` and do without the `self-join`, that might help your query a bit.

Can you put up in a sample dataset to get a better understanding. 
From your query it seems there are multiple rows for one set of useridet, userid. Need more info clarity...

---

Try this...

```
declare @MyTable table
(UserID int, StartDate datetime, FinishDate datetime);

insert into @MyTable values
('1', '2013-11-25 14:25', '2013-11-25 16:35'),
('2', '2013-12-01 10:20', '2013-12-02 12:20'),
('2', '2013-12-06 09:15', '2013-12-06 16:15'),
('1', '2013-12-08 08:00', '2013-12-08 16:30'),
('1', '2013-12-09 07:45', '2013-12-15 09:45');



 select
  FinishDate New_Start_dt,        
  LEAD(startdate,1,NULL) over(partition by userid order by startdate) New_finish_dt,
  DATEDIFF(minute,FinishDate,LEAD(StartDate,1,NULL) over(partition by userid order by StartDate)) as DifHours
        from @MyTable
```

Comment: this is much faster than CTE version. LEAD is new to my - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think... this is the solution:

```
declare @MyTable table
(UserID int, StartDate datetime, FinishDate datetime);

insert into @MyTable values

('1', '2013-11-25 14:25', '2013-11-25 16:35'),
('1', '2013-12-08 08:00', '2013-12-08 16:30'),
('2', '2013-12-06 09:15', '2013-12-06 16:15'),
('2', '2013-12-01 10:20', '2013-12-02 12:20'),
('1', '2013-12-09 07:45', '2013-12-15 09:45');


with CTE_RN as
(
    select
        UserID,
        StartDate,
        FinishDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserID,StartDate) as RN
    from @MyTable
)

select
    s.UserID,
    f.FinishDate,
    s.StartDate,
    DATEDIFF(minute, f.FinishDate, s.StartDate) as DifMin
from CTE_RN as f
inner join CTE_RN as s
    on s.RN = f.RN + 1
    where s.UserID=f.UserID
```